# migrate to flutter, access keychain

Tags: ios, flutter, keychain

I'm trying to convert an app developed with iOS native to Flutter. But I don't want to lose the data stored in the keychain. After switching to Flutter, how do I access the values I saved in keychain in the iOS native app? Do I need to make the Bundle Identifier the same and set the same group ID in key chain sharing? Is that all I need to do?

Comment: You need to keep the bundle id the same anyway; otherwise it isn't the same app. If you have used a keychain group then, yes, you need to continue to use that.